# Erro 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute '_builtin_function_or_method_to_mysql' PYTHON

Tags: mysql, python

No consigo ejecutar bien mis códigos usando *Python* y *MySQL* en el *cmd* me sale errores de que me faltan argumentos.

```
"""
Proyecto Python y Mysql:
- Abrir asistente
- Login o registro
- Si elegimos registro, creara un usuario en la bbdd
- Si elegimos login, identica el usuario y nos preguntara
- Crear nota, mostrar notas, borrarlas.
"""
from usuarios import acciones

print("""
Acciones disponibles:
    -registro
    -login
""")

hazEl = acciones.Acciones()
accion = input("Que quieres hacer?: ")

if accion == "registro":
    hazEl.registro()

elif accion =="login":
    hazEl.login()
```

Código usuario:

```
import datetime
import mysql.connector

database = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="master_python",
    port=3306
)

cursor = database.cursor(buffered=True)

class Usuario:

    def __init__(self, nombre, apellidos, email, password):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellidos = apellidos
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

    def registrar(self):
        fecha = datetime.datetime.now

        sql ="INSERT INTO Usuarios VALUES(null, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        usuario = (self.nombre, self.apellidos, self.email, self.password, fecha)

        cursor.execute(sql, usuario)
        database.commit()

        return (cursor.rowcount, self)

    def identicar(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Acciones:

```
import usuarios.usuario as modelo

class Acciones:

    def registro(self):
        print("\nOk!!! Vamos a registrarte en el sistema...")

        nombre = input("Cual es tu nombre?: ")
        apellidos = input("Cual es tu apellido?: ")
        email = input("Introduce tu email: ")
        password = input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")

        usuario = modelo.Usuario(nombre, apellidos, email, password)
        registro = usuario.registrar()

        if registro[0] >=1:
            print(f"Perfecto {registro[1].nombre} te has registrado con el email {registro[1].email}")

        else:
            print("No te has registrado")

    def login(self):
        print("\n Vale!! Identificate en el sistema...")
        email = input("Introduce tu email: ")
        password = input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")
```

Base de datos:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS master_python;
use master_python;

CREATE TABLE usuarios(
id          int(25) auto_increment not null,
nombre      varchar(100),
apellidos   varchar(255),
email       varchar(255) not null,
password    varchar(255) not null,
fecha       date not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT uq_email UNIQUE(email)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE notas(
id          int(25) auto_increment not null,
usuario_id  int(25) not null,
titulo      varchar(255) not null,
descripcion MEDIUMTEXT,
fecha       date not null,
CONSTRAINT pk_notas PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_nota_usuario FOREIGN KEY(usuario_id) REFERENCES usuarios(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

Me muestra los siguientes errores:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py",
> line 183, in to_mysql
> return getattr(self, "_{0}_to_mysql".format(type_name))(value) AttributeError: 'MySQLConverter' object has no attribute
> '_builtin_function_or_method_to_mysql'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
> line 432, in _process_params
> res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]   File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
> line 432, in 
> res = [to_mysql(i) for i in res]   File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py",
> line 185, in to_mysql
> raise TypeError("Python '{0}' cannot be converted to a " TypeError: Python 'builtin_function_or_method' cannot be converted to
> a MySQL type
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\pedro\Desktop\master_course\20-proyectos-python\main.py",
> line 21, in 
> hazEl.registro()   File "C:\Users\pedro\Desktop\master_course\20-proyectos-python\usuarios\acciones.py",
> line 14, in registro
> registro = usuario.registrar()   File "C:\Users\pedro\Desktop\master_course\20-proyectos-python\usuarios\usuario.py",
> line 28, in registrar
> cursor.execute(sql, usuario)   File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
> line 557, in execute
> psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))   File "C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
> line 436, in _process_params
> raise errors.ProgrammingError( mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing
> format-parameters; Python 'builtin_function_or_method' cannot be
> converted to a MySQL type
>
> C:\Users\pedro\Desktop\master_course\20-proyectos-python>

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas. Te faltarían los paréntesis del método `now()` en el momento de crear la variable `fecha`. Seria `fecha = datatime.datatime.now()`

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

tuve el mismo problema.

No encontre otra solución mas que la siguiente:

En primer lugar, vi que el error era por la libreria 'datetime' y era necesario evitar importarla y sobre todo utilizarla. Por ello, elimine la columna "fecha" de la tabla de la base de datos, y borre de todo el codigo las acciones con fecha.

de esa forma me dejo de saltar el error.